# Phoenix framework : pass changeset errors between controllers

Tags: redirect, parameter-passing, phoenix-framework

When I submit my form, I would like to redirect on the same page if there are errors (showing changeset errors on the view).

But actually my webpage comes from a "LandingController" and the verification is done on a "UserController"

If I use "redirect" I don't know how to pass changeset errors from "UserController" to  "LandingController".

If I use "`render/3`" it means my web page exist at least twice: one as a view of "LandinController" and one as a view of "userController".

I think I can do the second solution but it means there are sereval page duplicated when there are forms on them.

Is there another solution ? What is the properest way to proceed ?

Actually  my code looks like this :

[view from the LandingController]

```
<%= form_for @changeset, user_path(@conn, :create), [class: "formulaire"], fn f -> %>
   <%= select f, :genders, Enum.map(@genders, &{&1.name, &1.id}), prompt: "Sexe"%>

   <%= email_input f, :email %>
   <%= error_tag f, :email %>

   <%= text_input f, :lastname %>
   <%= error_tag f, :lastname %>

   <%= text_input f, :firstname %>
   <%= error_tag f, :firstname %>

   <%= hidden_input f, :redirect_to, value: @conn.request_path %>

   <%= submit "Submit" %>
 <% end %>
```

[part of my UserController]

```
def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
  case Accounts.create_user(user_params) do
    {:ok, user} ->
      conn
      |> put_flash(:info, "User created successfully.")
      |> redirect(to: user_path(conn, :show, user))
    {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset} ->
      genders = HexProject.Repo.all(
        from g in Gender,
        select: %{name: g.name, id: g.id}
      )

      conn
      |> put_flash(:error, "User was not created.")
      |> redirect(to: user_params["redirect_to"])
      #|> render("new.html", changeset: changeset, genders: genders)
  end
end
```

Comment: I do not really understand your reasoning for something like this. But you could throw the information into the users session, then on the redirected page read and clear that session information. But `render/3` is generally the thing you should be using here.

Comment: I edited a big part of my post. I don't know if it's clearer like this ? My goal is to pass changeset errors, that I can display if I use `render/3` (but I don't like the `render/3` solution), between two controllers

Comment: Why are you using your `LandingController` for the new user form instead of the `UserController`? I think this is where you issue stems from.

Comment: Ooh ! Yes, using a user route like 

`user_path  GET     /user            HexProjectWeb.UserController :index` and
`user_path  GET     /users           HexProjectWeb.UserController :index`

will resolve the problem. And in this case it's ok (because it's my home page). I wonder why I didn't think about it before.

But, in another context, if I have a page with 2 or 3 "wild forms" about different subjects  I can not use this solution. Will asynchronous forms resolve the problem ?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "wild forms". I'm also not sure what you mean by "asynchronous forms", my best guess is that you meant submitting the forms using something like AJAX?

Comment: Sorry it's just an expression that I use in french (because I am french) and I tried to use it in English. I mean having forms which are not about the main subject of the page. And yes for the second part, the purpose was to submit forms using AJAX.